# java web start requesting jar file multiple times

Tags: java, java-web-start, icedtea-web

I'm using icedtea javaws (version: icedtea-web 1.6.2 (1.6.2-3ubuntu1)) to distribute my java application.

My jnlp file looks like this:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="/">  
    <information>  
            <title>My Application</title>  
        <vendor>Software Studio</vendor>      
        <offline-allowed/>  
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <jar href="MyApplication-1.0.jar"></jar>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.myapp.application.Application">
        <!-- Application Arguments -->
    </application-desc>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>    
</jnlp>
```

The application jnlp file and the resource MyApplication-1.0.jar file are hosted in an apache web server.
I've noticed in the access logs that some clients are requesting the jar file multiple times in a short period of time. Below is a snippet of the content of my apache access_log file showing this issue:

```
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:48:24 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:48:30 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:48:36 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:48:43 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:48:49 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:48:55 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:01 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:07 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:13 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:20 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:26 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:33 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:39 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:45 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:51 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:49:57 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:50:03 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:50:10 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:50:16 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:50:22 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:50:28 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:50:34 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:50:42 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
172.3.95.128 (85.58.55.24) - - [03/Jan/2020:12:50:46 +0000] "GET /MyApplication-1.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 20308737 "-" "Java/1.8.0_222"
```

Clients are running application by executing the javaws command passing the jnlp url as a parameter.

```
javaws -headless https://myapplication.com/MyApplication.jnlp
```

What can be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

IcedTea-Web 1.6.x is a rather old version.
Can you try to update to 1.8.x or give openwebstart.com a try.
It is based on IcedTea-Web 2.0.x and provides some additional features